# How to store output of meminfo command to a variable in shell script

Tags: shell, output

> Hi dear friends I have a shell script command for store output of
>   /proc/meminfo command in some variables and I want to sum these
>   variables, but I got just this result kB+KB+KB and the code doesn't
>   work,can anybody help to fix it,thanks

```
numA=$(grep -m 1 "MemTotal" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $2 }')
numB=$(grep -m 1 "MemFree" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $3 }')
numC=$(grep -m 1 "Buffers" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $4 }')
numD=$(grep -m 1 "Cached" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $5 }')
echo "-------------------"
echo $numA $numB $numC $numD
echo " ****--------------------"
numsum=$numB+$numC+$numD
echo  "numsum =MemFree+Buffers+Cached=$numsum"
echo $numsum
numminus=$mumA-$numsum
echo  "numminus =MemTotal-(MemFree+Buffers+Cached)=$numminus"
numDivide=$numminus/$numA
echo  "numDivide =numminus/numA=$numsum"
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing should be a single Awk script. Extracting each field to a separate shell variable so you can use the shell's notoriously poor arithmetic facilities is just crazy. In particular, even if you do get some arithmetic in Bash (though the syntax is different from what you tried), it will still be integer only; so your division result will simply be zero.

```
awk '/MemTotal/ && !memtotal { memtotal = $2 }
    /MemFree/ && !memfree { memfree = $3 }
    /Buffers/ &&!buffers { buffers = $4 }
    /Cached/ && !cached { cached = $5 }
    END (
        # Ugh, is this really necessary?
        print "-------------------"
        print memtotal, memfree, buffers, cached
        print " ****-------------------"
        numsum=memfree+buffers+cached
        print "numsum =MemFree+Buffers+Cached=" numsum
        numminus=memtotal-numsum
        print "numminus =MemTotal-(MemFree+Buffers+Cached)=" numminus
        numDivide=numminus/memtotal
        print  "numDivide =numminus/memtotal=" numDivide }' /proc/meminfo
```

If one of the values could be zero, this may require a slightly different approach for pulling out the first match.

I renamed the first four variables; the other three should probably get sensible names instead as well, but I could not quickly understand what you are hoping to calculate.

A somewhat more idiomatic approach for capturing the result of the calculation for later use is to have the Awk script print just the computer-readable output.  The following script is rich in comments -- it could be pared down to be much smaller if you remove the comments, but I suppose legibility and maintainability would trump brevity here.  Incidentally, this also demonstrates the "slightly different approach" to ensure that we always get the first value of a variable.

```
memRatio=$(awk '# Populate an associative array with first occurrences
    /MemTotal/ && !("memtotal" in i) { i["memtotal"] = $2 }
    /MemFree/ && !("memfree" in i) { i["memfree"] = $3 }
    /Buffers/ && !("buffers" in i) { i["buffers"] = $4 }
    /Cached/ && !("cached" in i) { i["cached"] = $5 }
    # Have we collected all the keys for the array? Then print and quit
    ("memtotal" in i) && ("memfree" in i) && 
        ("buffers" in i) && ("cached" in i) {
            print (i["memtotal"]-i["memfree"]-i["buffers"]-i["cached"])/i["memtotal"]
            exit 0 # success
         }
    # If we fall through to here, we never captured the variables
    END { exit 1 }' /proc/meminfo)
```

Though on my system, all these values seem to be in `$2`, not in successively increasing columns.  In this case, the capturing code could be simplified somewhat (use a single regex for all four keys; use the regex match regardless of case for the array key).

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually I want to store Memtotal and MemFree and buffers and cache in different variable and do this, MemTotal-(MemFree+buffers+cache)/MemTotal and store the result in a variable to use in a java program :)

Comment: Is there any particular detail you still have trouble with?

Comment: Yes actually there is still a problem...in this line echo  numDivide=$numminus/$numA  the result of division that this line shows is zero, but I know according to numminus and numA it would be 0.123 how can I divide these to numbers to show digits after point and save the the 0.123 in a variable as float number.thanks

Comment: The Awk script replaces your attempt. The code here does not suffer from the limitations of the shell. The value in `memRatio` is the result you seek.

Answer (score 1):

I only modify the scripts so that it returns some values. I am not an expert but i only fixed error that where visible to me. Hope it works for you.

```
numA=$(grep -m 1 "MemTotal" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $2 }')
numB=$(grep -m 1 "MemFree" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $2 }')
numC=$(grep -m 1 "Buffers" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $2 }')
numD=$(grep -m 1 "Cached" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $2 }')

echo "-------------------"
echo $numA $numB $numC $numD
echo " ****--------------------"
numsum=$(($numB+$numC+$numD))
echo  "numsum =MemFree+Buffers+Cached=$numsum"
echo $numsum
numminus=$mumA-$numsum
echo  "numminus =MemTotal-(MemFree+Buffers+Cached)=$numminus"
numDivide=$numminus/$numA
echo  "numDivide =numminus/numA=$numsum"
```

Comment: Thanks Dear friend but when I use "numDivide =numminus/numA=$numsum" the result is "0" do you know what is the problem?and How can I fix it?

Comment: I am getting the following result after my modification. I didn't getting any 0 !!!! . Or i am missing something.
         -------------------
         3948080 349836 158340 1237468
         ****--------------------
        numsum =MemFree+Buffers+Cached=1745644
        1745644
       numminus =MemTotal-(MemFree+Buffers+Cached)=-1745644
       numDivide =numminus/numA=1745644

Comment: Thank you I fixed it:),Mt Totalmem was2837436,numsum was 1781384,numminus was 1056652, I calculated the division by calculator it's result is, 0.371 but the script just shows  zero!!! Do you know How should I change the division command that result shows 0.371,Thanks

Comment: Bash only supports integer arithmetic. See my answer instead, or fiddle with `bc`.